# Implementing JOptionPane in Java

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I created this popup window which will show up in response to a button being clicked in my gui. I have two questions regarding this.

1. How do I get rid of the text field below the radio buttons?
2. I need to check which radio button was selected once the ok button is clicked but I didn't create that button. So how would I implement the actionPerformed function for that?

My code:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    if(evt.getSource() == jButton2)
         optionPopup();
} 

private void optionPopup(){
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JRadioButton undergraduateButton = new JRadioButton();
    JRadioButton graduateButton = new JRadioButton();
    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();

    undergraduateButton.setText("Option A");
    graduateButton.setText("Option B");
    group.add(undergraduateButton);
    group.add(graduateButton);
    panel.add(undergraduateButton);
    panel.add(graduateButton);

    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(panel);
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Use `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` instead of `JOptionPane.showInputDialog`

   if you still want to have `?` icon instead of `!` one, use

   ```
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel, "title", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
   ```

   you can also remove icon by using `JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE`

   If you want to make sure that client pressed OK button use

   ```
   int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel, "title", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
   ```

   If `response` will be `-1` it means window was closed by `X` button, if it was `0` user pressed `OK`.

   More info at: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

---

2. Use `undergraduateButton.isSelected()` and `graduateButton.isSelected()` to see if one of them was selected.

Comment: The first part worked like a charm, thank you. As for the second question, I assume the methods you have provided will respond whenever the either button is selected. But I only want to know which button is selected after the ok button is clicked. For that would I use the OK_OPTION method in JOptionPane before I check for which button has been selected?

Comment: Never mind I think I figured it out. It might be better to use showConfirmDialog in this case since it returns a value based on which button is clicked. Still thank you for your help

Comment: @Aeleon In that case you can try `int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel, "title", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);`. If response is `0` OK button was pressed, if it was `-1` dialog was closed with `X` button. Based on that result you can proceed farther.

Comment: @Aeleon Oh, didn't see your previous comment :)

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're trying to do is referred to as **Direct Use** of the JOptionPane.  [Refer to the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) for more details.

```
 JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(arguments);
 pane.set.Xxxx(...); // Configure
 JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(parentComponent, title);
 dialog.show();
```